# fs.writeFileSync not writing to specified file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to update a file content on my node server but the fs.writeFileSync failing to write to the specified file without throwing any error, I have this same exact line in other methods in the code but this specific line is not performing the write operation and also not throwing any error.

```
"negotiate": function(menu){
    if (menu) {
        //this would be changed later to the appropraite request
        //get url from menu
        //getting task list quesions
        menu = fs.readFileSync(rootPath + menu.output, 'utf8');
        menu = JSON.parse(menu);
    }
    var userData = fs.readFileSync(this.pathToUserTable(), 'utf8');
    userData = JSON.parse(userData);

    userData = this.updateUserDataForNegotiate(userData, menu);
    //fs.unlinkSync(this.pathToUserTable());
    try{
        fs.writeFileSync(this.pathToUserTable(), JSON.stringify(userData));//not writing to file
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);//no error thrown
    }
    this.res.send(menu);
},
```

`this.pathToUserTable()` returns the equivalent of `rootPath + "/database/users/" + this.req.query.msisdn + ".json"`, where `var rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + "/../../");`. I have tested this method and am sure it works.

I have am also certain that this also returns the appropriate date `JSON.stringify(userData)`.

At this point I think it is strange.

Added just I added a timeout to the fs write method and it works, I am guessing that the file is unavailable at the time of this fs write method is called so the write does not happen.

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function(){
    fs.writeFileSync(that.pathToUserTable(), JSON.stringify(userData));
    console.log(that.pathToUserTable(), "   ", JSON.stringify(userData));
}, 5);
```

So how do I wait for the previous `fs.writeFileSync` method to complete before doing this one?

Comment: What does `this.pathToUserTable()` return exactly?

Comment: it can because the file path is incorrect, try to path by another way, like using `__dirname+'../'`

Comment: @farhadamjady `__dirname` never contains a trailing slash, so that would fail.

Comment: The whole idea of `fs.writeFileSync` is that it has completed when it returns.  Are `this.updateUserDataForNegotiate` and/or `this.pathToUserTable` asynchronous functions perhaps?

Comment: @robertklep, no they are not at all, I am thinking of using a while statement to check for the file content if it is equal to `userData`

Comment: @Sabi that doesn't fix the underlying problem though :D (although at this point I have no idea what that is).

Comment: @robertklep, yeah but I need to move on for now, it been 32 hours setback so far. would come back to it if I get an answer.